# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.26 in my ubuntu server, I've installed Oracle JDK and here is the output of
`java -version` command

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

And output of javac -version command is :

```
javac 1.7.0_51
```

I didn't specify JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME manually and I've installed JDK from ppa:webupd8team repository.

And in my windows machine I export my web project to war file with Eclipse and compiler version of it is 1.7, I checked it in Properties of my project, in Java Compiler section, configuration is below :

```
Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.7' on the Java Build Path
```

In Installed JREs section in my Eclipse, default one is JDK 1.7.0_45. I also checked major version of my compiled java classes with

```
javap -verbose MyClass | findstr "major"
```

command and it is 51. But I get this exception below from Tomcat in ubuntu :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/maozturk/MyClass : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Why am I getting this exception since version of them are same?

Comment: You are running your Tomcat under Java 6.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I forgot to specify Tomcat version and I added it, version is 7.0.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know exactly what problem is but it solved when I upgrade Tomcat to 7.0.52.

Answer (score 0):

I know that topic is about Tomcat, but I had the same problem with Glassfish, maybe it could be helpful - I've changed java version for Glassfich to java 1.8 (after install it :) )